# AngularJS render html as string

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

In my web app, when I go to one of my url, angularjs returns me haml template as a plain text.
But if I go to my root url it works fine. I use Rails 3.2.13, AngularJS 1.1.4, Haml for views.

This is my app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

```
!!! 5
%html{'ng-app' => 'myproject'}
  %head
    %title MyProject
    = favicon_link_tag
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tag

    %body
      .main-background
      .app{'ng-view' => ''}
        = yield
```

This is my app/assets/javascripts/main.js.coffee

```
@app = angular.module('myproject', [])
```

This is my app/assets/javascripts/routes.js.coffee

```
app.config ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->

  $routeProvider
  .when '/',
    templateUrl: '/assets/signin/index.haml',
    controller: 'SignInController'

  .when '/signup/:code',
    templateUrl: '/assets/signup/index.haml',
    controller: 'SignUpController',

]
```

I have 2 controllers in app/asssets/javascripts/controllers/ respectively. They both are emty.
I also use html5 push state, lik this(push_state.js.coffee)

```
app.config ($locationProvider) ->
  $locationProvider.html5Mode true
```

And, I have views, in app/assets/templates, whith path, that I wrote in templateUrl.

My problem is, when I go to '/', angularjs render my view fine, but, when I go to the second url, it returns me a plain text in span tag, with haml template inside it. I tried to use only one when statement with the second template and it was the same result.
And, the question is what should I do to render my second view properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It strange, but when I do some edit in my templates, and revert then back, after that all templates render properly. In both cases, before edit and after, templates have the same markup.